# Use OS X lion 10.7.2 disk image to restore a Lion Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have a disk image of OS X lion 10.7.2. I have read that certain disc images won't work to restore Macs that shipped with Lion installed.

I was wondering if my 10.7.2 disc image can be used to restore a Mac that shipped with Lion?

Comment: If you install it to a flash drive, it might create a restore partition on that drive.  Then you can boot off that drive.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718 read the part "What to do if the installer warns that no Recovery HD can be created"